# Scikit: how to check if an object is a RandomizedSearchCV or a RandomForestClassifier?

Tags: python-2.7, types, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

I have a few classifiers that have been created using [Grid Search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV.html), and others that have been created directly as [Random Forests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

The random forests return type   `sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier`, and the random forests created with gridSearch return type `sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV`.

I am trying to programmatically check the type of the estimator (in order to decide if I need to use `best_estimator_` on [feature importances](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.feature_importances_)), but can't seem to find a good way to do so.

`if type(estimator) == 'sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV'` was my first guess, but is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **type()** function doesn't return a classinfo, it returns a **type object**. So comparing equality to a classinfo like that won't work.

What you need to do is use **isinstance(object, classinfo)** to test the type of your estimator.

This function returns True if the type matches the classinfo and False if it doesn't.

Let's say you created an estimator of type

> sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier

Then

> isinstance(estimator, sklearn.ensemble.forest.RandomForestClassifier)

would return True, while

> isinstance(estimator,sklearn.grid_search.RandomizedSearchCV)

would return False.

You could then use that result in tests such as if statements.

Remember to

> import sklearn

to have access to all the scikit-learn classinfo you might need to test against.